# Why does the control directly enter the catch block without entering the try block in this SSCCE?

Tags: java, exception

In the following SSCCE, why does the `catch` block keep executing again and again, resulting in an infinite loop?

When I run this program and was prompted to enter an integer, I entered `a`.

What I thought would happen was that, an `InputMismatchException` would be thrown on the first line inside the `try` block, and from there, the control will go to the `catch` block, where it would print `` once, and then go the the next iteration of `while(true)` loop, in which it should have entered the `try` block again and should have prompted me to enter the integer.

But it seems to have started an unending entering into the catch block as soon as it enters the `while(true)` loop, because if it was entering the try block, it would have prompted me to enter an integer again.

**Where, and what, is the mistake?**

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class WhyThisInfiniteLoop {

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in); 
        int i = 0; 
        System.out.println("Please enter an integer: ");

        while(true){
          try{
             i = reader.nextInt();
             break;  
          }catch(InputMismatchException ex){
             System.out.println("You did not enter an int. Please enter an integer:");
          }
        }

        System.out.println("Input of type int: " + i);
    }

}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Please enter an integer:
a
You did not enter an int. Please enter an integer:
You did not enter an int. Please enter an integer:
You did not enter an int. Please enter an integer:
You did not enter an int. Please enter an integer:
You did not enter an int. Please enter an integer:
You did not enter an int. Please enter an integer:
You did not enter an int. Please enter an integer:
You did not enter an int. Please enter an integer:
You did not enter an int. Please enter an integer:
You did not enter an int. Please enter an integer:
You did not enter an int. Please enter an integer:
You did not enter an int. Please enter an integer:
You did not enter an int. Please enter an integer:
You did not enter an int. Please enter an integer:
You did not enter an int. Please enter an integer:
You did not enter an int. Please enter an integer:
You did not enter an int. Please enter an integer:
You did not enter an int. Please enter an integer:
You did not enter an int. Please enter an integer:
You did not enter an int. Please enter an integer:
You did not enter an int. Please enter an integer:
You did not ...
...
...
```

Comment: Given the theory that you were not entering the try block, you should have put a println at the start of the try block. That would have told you something else was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you aren't reading the thing (a *token*) that isn't an `int` in your `catch` block. Try something like

```
try {
    i = reader.nextInt();
    break;  
} catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
    System.out.printf("%s is not an int. Please enter an integer:", reader.next());
}
```

It would be enough to call `reader.next()` (which will consume the token).

As is, your `Scanner` says `nextInt` which results in an error that there isn't an `int`. And then loops trying to read an `int` (and *failing*).